# How to count the occurrences of words from one table to comments in another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to accomplish a task in Google's BigQuery which may require logic I am not sure SQL can handle natively.

I have 2 tables:

1. First table has a single column where each row is a single lowercase word
2. Second table is a database of comments (with data like who made the comment, the comment itself, timestamp etc)

I want sort the comments in the second table by the number of occurrences of the words in the first table.

Here is a basic example of what I want to do, using python, using letters instead of words... but you get the idea:

```
words = ['a','b','c','d','e']

comments = ['this is the first sentence', 'this is another comment', 'look another sentence, which is also a comment', 'nope', 'no', 'run']

wordcount = {}

for comment in comments:
    for word in words:
        if word in comment:
            if comment in wordcount:
                wordcount[comment] += 1
            else:
                wordcount[comment] = 1

print(sorted(wordcount.items(), key = lambda k: k[1], reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[('look another sentence, which is also a comment', 3), ('this is another comment', 3), ('this is the first sentence', 2), ('nope', 1)]
```

The best thing I have seen so far for generating an SQL query is doing something like the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    table
WHERE
    comment_col like '%word1%'
    OR comment_col like '%word2%'
    OR ...
```

But there are over 2000 words... it just doesn't feel right. Any tips?

Comment: As you use *letters instead of words*, I can understand why do you get that output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT comment, COUNT(word) AS cnt
FROM comments
JOIN words
ON STRPOS(comment, word) > 0 
GROUP BY comment
-- ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

As an option you can use regexp if you wish:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT comment, COUNT(word) AS cnt
FROM comments
JOIN words
ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(comment, word)
GROUP BY comment
-- ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

You can test / play with above using dummy example from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH words AS (
  SELECT word
  FROM UNNEST(['a','b','c','d','e']) word
),
comments AS (
  SELECT comment 
  FROM UNNEST(['this is the first sentence', 'this is another comment', 'look another sentence, which is also a comment', 'nope', 'no', 'run']) comment
)
SELECT comment, COUNT(word) AS cnt
FROM comments
JOIN words
ON STRPOS(comment, word) > 0 
GROUP BY comment
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Update for :

> Do have any quick suggestions to do full string match only?

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH words AS (
  SELECT word
  FROM UNNEST(['a','no','is','d','e']) word
),
comments AS (
  SELECT comment 
  FROM UNNEST(['this is the first sentence', 'this is another comment', 'look another sentence, which is also a comment', 'nope', 'no', 'run']) comment
)
SELECT comment, COUNT(word) AS cnt
FROM comments
JOIN words
ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(comment, CONCAT(r'\b', word, r'\b')) 
GROUP BY comment
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, I believe this is working as I described. But I have found that there are too many substring matches. Do have any quick suggestions to do full string match only? Also I am not limited to standardSQL, I thought that was the only thing BigQuery supported, but it seems like it can do more.

Comment: You are the best! Thanks for your help. Gonna go and read up on more SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it well, I think you need a query like this:

```
select comment, count(*) cnt
from comments
join words
  on comment like '% ' + word + ' %'   --this checks for `... word ..`; a word between spaces
  or comment like word + ' %'          --this checks for `word ..`; a word at the start of comment
  or comment like '% ' + word          --this checks for `.. word`; a word at the end of comment
  or comment = word                    --this checks for `word`; whole comment is the word
group by comment
order by count(*) desc
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo as a sample**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9600)